# What does "i.c." mean?

Tags: abbreviations

This is a scholarly footnote: "Ferrarius, lib. i.c. iii p. 108."

I do not understand what "i.c." means.

Comment: I suspect that your spacing is wrong in grouping them together: "lib. i." is Book One, "c. iii" is Chapter Three.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is apparently based on a false premise.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Donovan, for your thoughtful answer. If you will google, however, you will find many references to "lib. i.c."

Answer (score 1):

Google turns up many instances of "lib. i. c.", but there are actually more instances of "lib. ii. c." and "lib. iii. c.". I agree with @brian-Donovan: you are mis-grouping and so mis-interpreting the reference: "Ferrarius, lib. i.c. iii p. 108." means "Ferrarius, Book 1, Chapter Three, Page 108".

Comment: By the way, I spent quite a while Googling, looking for an explicit interpretation of the "lib." and "c." portions of the reference, and found nothing. Interesting that Google is a great resource for some things, but absolutely useless for others.